# error opening terminal: xterm-256color

Tags: ssh, terminal

I logged into *metasploitable* from kali linux using SSH.(Windows host)

Now I want to access file named config.inc (`/var/www/mutillidae/config.inc`) in *metasploitable*.

I tried opening it using `sudo nano /var/www/mutillidae/config.inc` command and it showed me an error.

> error opening terminal: xterm-256color

- How to overcome this error?
- Is there any problem as I opened it using SSH?

Comment: Try `sudo less /var/www/mutillidae/config.inc` and use `ssh -X` instead of just `ssh`

Comment: try `sudo vi /var/www/mutillidae/config.inc`

Comment: It gave me a warning(terminal is not fully functional). and then opened the file. When I tried to open it using less.

Comment: and then opened the file.

Comment: @abhijithpogiri: Don't comment your own question, but **edit your question** to improve it by giving details.

Comment: Ok. I will do that. I am a newbie, that's why i donno.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It seems like you have a problem with the terminal definition.

Try using `xterm` instead of `xterm-256color`

```
export TERM=xterm
```

or the following terminal setting:

```
export TERMINFO=/etc/terminfo
export TERM=linux
```

Also, if you still have problem with `nano` try using `vi` which is a simple editor and doesn't required much from the terminal

```
sudo vi /var/www/mutillidae/config.inc
```

Comment: Thanks. After changing it from xterm-256color to xterm, it worked.

Comment: @abhijithpogiri - great, if my answer solve your question, please [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.